# Need to wrap certain parts of a string of email addresses in quotes

Tags: ruby

Given a string such as this:

```
Bob Smith <bobsmith@gmail.com>, Jones, Rich A. <richjones@gmail.com>
```

I need to produce a string like this:

```
Bob Smith <bobsmith@gmail.com>, "Jones, Rich A." <richjones@gmail.com>
```

Or alternatively (if this is easier):

```
"Bob Smith" <bobsmith@gmail.com>, "Jones, Rich A." <richjones@gmail.com>
```

What's the most elegant way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do gsub, or scan.  Either way a regex is most elegant.  I recommend a scan, so you will have the option to go through each email address and do whatever you want to it (including deciding whether or not to quote the name).

```
str = Bob Smith <bobsmith@gmail.com>, Jones, Rich A. <richjones@gmail.com>
email_addrs = []

str.scan(/\s*(.*?)\s*<(.+?)>(?:,|\Z)/) do |match|
  # yields ["Bob Smith", "bobsmith@gmail.com"]
  # then   ["Jones, Rich A.", "richjones@gmail.com"]

  email_addrs << "\"#{match.first}\" <#{match.last}>"
end

email_addrs.join(", ") #=> "Bob Smith" <bobsmith@gmail.com>, "Jones, Rich A." <richjones@gmail.com>
```

Good luck!

Comment: It'd work for the scenario asked about, but it wouldn't handle someone who had quotation marks in their name. I'm not sure if a regex is the best solution. That being said, I'm not sure what the alternative would be.

Answer (score 1):

You could get fancy with a regex, and I'm sure someone will spend the time to build one, but if you want something that makes sense:

```
# s is the string
def add_quotes(s)
  s = s.split
  new_s = []
  s.each do |w|
    unless w.index('<') == 0 && w.index('>') == w.length-1
      new_s << "\"#{w}\""
    else
      new_s << w
    end
  end

  new_s.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this, but this wouldn't handle a quotation mark in the name.

Comment: @Andrew - Why? What would it do instead?

Comment: It'd fail to do any special escaping for the quotation mark. So you'd get `"George "Dubya" Bush" <dubya@whitehouse.gov>` which would confuse the next parser no end.

Answer (score -1):

Build a regular expression that matches the "names", and replace each occurrence in a loop with the same string enclosed in quotes. Look at the `String` class and the regex matchers, especially the ones that iterate over the matches.