# Need to wrap certain parts of a string of email addresses in quotes (version 2)

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a string such as this:

```
Bob Smith <bobsmith@gmail.com>, Jones, Rich A. <richjones@gmail.com>, \
peterbaker@gmail.com
```

I need to produce a string like this:

```
"Bob Smith" <bobsmith@gmail.com>, "Jones, Rich A." <richjones@gmail.com>,\
peterbaker@gmail.com
```

(The backslash \ just means the line continues and is not really broken.)

This is related to [Need to wrap certain parts of a string of email addresses in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654301/need-to-wrap-certain-parts-of-a-string-of-email-addresses-in-quotes) but I needed to modify the question.

Please note that not all email address will be in angled brackets and accompanied by a full name.

Comment: Why not fix the real problem, which is the format of the input string? Whatever is producing that is broken, IMHO.

Comment: The input string contains valid email addresses, and is in a commonly received format, say, from an email message parsed from a mbox file.

Comment: Strange. I've worked with mbox files before, and I've never seen a To: line where the email addresses were not properly delimited or quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that can handle arbitrary email addresses and even multiple commas in one name (such as "Jones, Jr., Winston A."). Rather than attempt a massive regex, I just split it into parts and group the ones that are not complete email addresses with the next part.

```
input = "Bob Smith <bobsmith@gmail.com>, Jones, Rich A. <richjones@gmail.com>, peterbaker@gmail.com"
parts = input.split /\s*,\s*/

addrs = []
savebin = ""

#Group the parts together
parts.each do |part|
  if part.include? "@"
    addrs << savebin + part
    savebin = ""
  else
    savebin = part + ", "
  end
end

#Quote the names
puts addrs.map { |addr| addr.gsub(/^(.*) (<.*)/, '"\1" \2') }
```

The output is:

```
"Bob Smith" <bobsmith@gmail.com>
"Jones, Rich A." <richjones@gmail.com>
peterbaker@gmail.com
```

To get the exact output you specified, append `.join(", ")` to the last line of code above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that all email addresses you receive are formatted like "user@host.domain", then it gets a little easier:

```
require 'pp'

addr_str = 'Bob Smith <bobsmith@gmail.com>, Jones, Rich A. <richjones@gmail.com>, peterbaker@gmail.com'

parsed_addresses = addr_str.scan(/\s*([\w., ]*?)\s*?(<?\w+@[\w.]+>?),?/) 
pp parsed_addresses

# >> [["Bob Smith", "<bobsmith@gmail.com>"],
# >>  ["Jones, Rich A.", "<richjones@gmail.com>"],
# >>  ["", "peterbaker@gmail.com"]]

pp parsed_addresses.map{ |name, email| [%Q{"#{name}"}, email] }

# >> [["\"Bob Smith\"", "<bobsmith@gmail.com>"],
# >>  ["\"Jones, Rich A.\"", "<richjones@gmail.com>"],
# >>  ["\"\"", "peterbaker@gmail.com"]]

puts parsed_addresses.map{ |name, email| [%Q{"#{name}"}, email] }

# >> "Bob Smith"
# >> <bobsmith@gmail.com>
# >> "Jones, Rich A."
# >> <richjones@gmail.com>
# >> ""
# >> peterbaker@gmail.com
```

In the real world, parsing and validating email addresses is a lot harder, so it can get really messy if you're pulling your email addresses from some source outside your enterprise's email directory.

In general, when doing this sort of thing you're better off expecting to do it in several (or many) lines of code, where you break the string apart into what appear to be sensible chunks, then normalize (or repair) the individual addresses.

Answer (score 0):

`s/(^|\s)([[:alpha:]].*?)(\s*<.*?>\s*(,|$))/$1"$2"$3/g`

The relationship would seem to be between `"Name" <email>,`. So, the more you know about Name (specifically), the better it can be.